# Labels and plot overlapping

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, ridgeline-plot

Is there is a way for the plot to not overlap with long labels of y axis in a ridge plot (seaborn). I am using the code of the example seaborn (slighty edited) in order to understand what I mean.

Thanks for any help.
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
names = ['15--Specialist COP',
         '16--Specialist other fieldcrops',
         '20--Specialist horticulture',
         '35--Specialist wine',
         '36--Specialist orchards - fruits',
         '37--Specialist olives',
         '38--Permanent crops combined',
         '45--Specialist milk',
         '48--Specialist sheep and goats',
         '49--Specialist cattle']
         # 'Specialist granivores',
         # 'Mixed crops',
         # 'Mixed livestock',
         # 'Mixed crops and livestock']
g = np.tile(names, 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)


# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)


g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried to add plt.tight_layout() before plt.show()?

Comment: The question is: How would you like it to look instead? Smaller labels? Shifted labels? Labels on in front with another color?

Comment: For me, the ideal solution would be to move the plot to the right but if it can't be done show the labels in front of the plot (another color)

Comment: Something like `g.set(yticks=[], xlim=(-5,None))`?